# Excel IF Formula 3

Tags: excel

I have a sheet with rows of data that I want to copy to a different sheet if the name in column a equals a certain value.  For example:

```
A       |   B     |    C
Name    |   Color |    Amount
Sue     |   Blue  |    $400
Joe     |   Green |    $1000
```

Sheet Sue needs to bring columns B and C from Sue's records to it's worksheet if column a equals Sue

Sheet Joe needs to bring columns B and C from Joe's records to it's worksheet if column a equals Joe

and so on and so forth...

Can anyone help!?

Comment: As shown in the link, you are not going to want to do this with formulas.  Your formulas would need to be array type and too many of those will cause the calculation times to slow and may even crash Excel.  You will want to code this in vba.  There are many example on the web on how to do this.

Comment: @ScottCraner - ...well, darn.  Good point though a VB solution is probably better if the data is a lot...

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you don't have too much data you can do this with array formulas.

Set up your main sheet (assuming it's `Sheet1`) with named ranges. Your `A2:A100` name it `Name`, `B2:B100`, name it `Color`,  and `C2:C100` name it `Amount`.  (Adjust the range as necessary)

Then, in each of the people's sheets, have header rows called `Name`, `Color`, and `Amount`.  Then you can use this formula (entered with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>):

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(A$1),SMALL(IF(INDIRECT($A$1)=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255),ROW(INDIRECT($A$1))-ROW(Sheet1!A$2)+1),ROWS(Sheet1!$A$2:A2)))
```

Wrap `IFERROR([formula],"")` to hide the `#NUM` errors when you reach the end of the data.

[image]

Comment: Yeah but that does not keep this from being a good answer.  though I would have used Aggregate instead of small, but 6 in one and half dozen in the other.

Comment: @ScottCraner yeah true. Also I'm still a young Padawan when it comes to `Aggregate`. Was fun to work on but I agree there's a better answer out there.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try tomorrow and let you know.  No, it is not a lot of data.  Maybe 30 rows (records) and only 10 columns.